# Extract a specific element from 3-tuple in dictionary

Tags: python

Given a dictionary:

```
self.mapping = {}  # key= IP, value = (mac,id,port)
```

Where the value is 3-tuple values. If I know the key, how do I get a specific element from the 3-tuple? For instance, I want to get `id` that corresponds to given `IP`.

Thank you.

Comment: `id = self.mapping["192.168.1.1"][1]`

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries and tuples are referenced using bracket notation. Dictionary values are referenced using corresponding keys; items in a tuple are referenced by index, using zero-based numbering (i.e. the first item in a tuple has the index 0, the second 1, and so on).

In your case, you can reference dictionary values using IP address keys:

```
self.mapping['IP address']
```

You can reference tuple items using indices:

```
my_tuple[1]
```

By combining the two, you can reference a specific item in a dictionary value tuple. In your example, ID is the second value at index 1, so you would use:

```
self.mapping['IP address'][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get()` method to properly unpack data from your dict in a pythonic way:

```
mac_addr, c_id, port = self.mapping.get('192.168.1.1', (None, None, None))
```

It avoids `KeyError` exception to be raised in case current IP is not in your dict.

If you only want to extract id field:

```
_, c_id, _ = self.mapping.get('192.168.1.1', (None, None, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use basic python sequences indexing.
According to your sample:

```
self.mapping['some IP'][1]
```

Check [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you get that whole tuple:

```
self.mapping["192.168.1.1"]
```

Then you just get the second element:

```
 self.mapping["192.168.1.1"][1]
```